# How could I restrict function param required in typescript?

Tags: typescript

```js
type cb = (str: string) => void

let demo1:cb=(str:string) => {return "anything"} //correct

let demo2:cb=(num:number) => {return "anything"} //error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

let demo3:cb=() => {return "anything"} //correct, why?
```

[demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAxgRlAvFAFAZ2AJwFxQ5gSwDsBzASiQD4oA3AewIBMBYAKABsJgpGIBbOgEZs8ROizZ8xclSgBvTFwCumIlABEAQyIhgAC2nqAvlAD0pmHUyKYwNp268BAJhFwxRJX2ye%20cCJgUiNQKyqoa2roGpMZmpgGYVlAAKuDQAORSpOlQBGhQRHTcmmhoBCREmnCcUMB0tWlQ6b7%20mOkAdPZcPPx0AMxuYkEhisAqalo6%20oYm5pbWELYANFAA7nogAPxsQA)

I want to restrict the param not empty ,someting error like this:

```js
let demo:cb=() => {return "anything"} //error , the param is required
```

Comment: many thanks,it is the answer